# How do I make the following bash code run

Tags: bash, shell

I aim to retrieve data from an API. The api returns,using curl, the nombre of sold graphic cards.
Here, the first code(#1) runs and active, but the second one and since I introduced a boocle for, it is not working.However, it seems to me that the both are similar. Please, is there any difference and why for the second one the program is not retrieving data, and if any advice to solve it. The Idea, I think that the output of the for loop must be declared to the call function so that the curl can do the job, I dont know.Thanks in advance. #1

```
#!/bin/bash
#Récupération des informations de vente des Carte graphiques

curl=$(which curl)

rtx3060=$(curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3060)
rtx3070=$(curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3070)
rtx3080=$(curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3080)
rtx3090=$(curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/rtx3090)
rx6700=$(curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/rx6700)

function graphic_card_count() {
 {
   echo "$(date)"
   echo "RTX3060: $rtx3060"
   echo "RTX3070: $rtx3070"
   echo "RTX3080: $rtx3080"
   echo "RTX3090: $rtx3090"
   echo "RX6700: $rx6700"
 }
}

graphic_card_count >> sales.txt
```

the output is similar to this:

```
Sat Nov 26 15:56:02 UTC 2022
RTX3060: 1
RTX3070: 10
RTX3080: 10
RTX3090: 18
RX6700: 13
```

Now the second code:
#2

```
#!/bin/bash
#Retrieval of graphics card sales information

graphic_cards=("rtx3060" "rtx3070" "rtx3080" "rtx3090" "rx6700")
curl_var="curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/"

# a for loop that will iterarte through the 'graphic_cards'
# and add the name_card at the end of the curl_var.

function graphic_cards_names(){

  for name_card in "${graphic_cards[@]}"; do
     echo "$name_card = \$(${curl_var}${name_card})"
  done
}

function main() {
   echo "$(date)"
   echo "RTX3060: $rtx3060"
   echo "RTX3070: $rtx3070"
   echo "RTX3080: $rtx3080"
   echo "RTX3090: $rtx3090"
   echo "RX6700: $rx6700"
}
main >> sales.txt
```

by the way, I tried calling the graphic_card_function inside the the main, but the output is similar to an echo, the curl not doing the job

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not create variables on the fly. Use arrays.

Do not store commands as variables. Use functions.

Just `date`. Do not use `echo $(command)`. Just the command

Your code could look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Retrieval of graphics card sales information

graphic_cards=("rtx3060" "rtx3070" "rtx3080" "rtx3090" "rx6700")

curl_it() {
   curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/"$1"
}

get_graphic_cards_names() {
    graphic_cards_names=()
    for name_card in "${graphic_cards[@]}"; do
       graphic_cards_names+=("$(curl_it "$name_card")")
    done
}

main() {
   date
   for idx in "${!graphic_cargs[@]}"; do
      echo "${graphic_cargs[idx]^^}: ${graphic_cards_names[idx]}"
   done
}

get_graphic_cards_names
main >> sales.txt
```

Comment: I'm speechless, thank alot for the help. it worked. and thank you for the advices

Comment: .1 Typo at line 20: *`graphic_cargs`*!  ( .2 line 4 could by shorten: `graphic_cards=(r{tx30{6..9},x670}0)` ;-b ) and maybe .3: as tagged bash and non ssl, `curl` could be not required if using `exec {get}<>/dev/tcp/127.0.0.1/5000` in a small dedicated function, mostly if expected answer is a small text string.